# WebRTC, remote stream can't be used, how to check if it's working (ReactJs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, mediastream

I've been working on a webRTC based video calling app, using react js and socket.io. first, it was stuck on negotiation needed, then later on I added event handlers to handle those events and followed the steps mentioned here: https://webrtc.org/getting-started/overview. I can see my own stream but nothing shows up for the remote stream, The streams are basically set in state and are MediaStream objects which are played by react-player. I've set add track on the callee side also, the connection is established and we can get the remote stream id too. Still can't get anything to play, a screenshot of chrome://webrtcinternals is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzPKA.png).

I've tried to play it without react-player, still have the same issue. on using useRef it's the same, nothing shows up on the remote stream. how to make sure that the stream is being transmitted, also the stream inside the console log shows up as active

Answer (score 0):

for those struggling with this issue, check if your browser is gathering ice candidates. for some reason unknown, it wasn't working with Brave browser, so I switched to firefox and it started playing.